# calculate timeline for different subjects in dataframe

Tags: r

I have data like

```
subject    date   number
1         1/2/01 4
1         3/2/01 6
1         10/2/01 7
2         1/1/01  2
2         4/1/01  3
```

I want to get R to work out the number of days since the first sample for each subject. eg:

```
Subject    days
1          0
1          2
1          9
2          0
2          3
```

How can I do this?  I have converted the dates using lubridate.

SOmething like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(data$date[i] != data$date[i -1]) {
        data$timeline <- data$date[i] - data$date[i-1]
    }
}
```

I get the error:
argument is of length 0 - I think the problem is the first line where there is no preceeding row..?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Comment: I think the last line of your example result should have the days equal to 62.

Comment: `require(data.table); setDT(data)[, number := date - min(date), by = subject]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dplyr` to do some grouping and data manipulation. Note that we first have to convert your date into something `R` will recognize as a date.

```
library(dplyr)
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$date, '%d/%m/%y')

dat %>%
    group_by(subject) %>%
    mutate(days = Date - min(Date))

#   subject date    number Date       days  
#     <int> <chr>    <int> <date>     <time>
# 1       1 1/2/01       4 2001-02-01 0     
# 2       1 3/2/01       6 2001-02-03 2     
# 3       1 10/2/01      7 2001-02-10 9     
# 4       2 1/1/01       2 2001-01-01 0     
# 5       2 4/3/01       3 2001-03-04 62
```

#### here's the data:

```
dat <- structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), date = c("1/2/01", 
"3/2/01", "10/2/01", "1/1/01", "4/3/01"), number = c(4L, 6L, 
7L, 2L, 3L), Date = structure(c(11354, 11356, 11363, 11323, 11385
), class = "Date")), .Names = c("subject", "date", "number", 
"Date"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the input shown in the note convert the date column to Date class (assuming that it is in the form dd/mm/yy) and then use `ave` to subtract the least date from all the dates for each subject.  If the input is sorted as in the question we could optionally use `x[1]` instead of `min(x)`. No packages are used.

```
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, "%d/%m/%y")
diff1 <- function(x) x - min(x)
with(data, data.frame(subject, days = ave(as.numeric(date), subject, FUN = diff1)))
```

giving:

```
  subject days
1       1    0
2       1    2
3       1    9
4       2    0
5       2   62
```

### Note

The input used, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "
subject    date   number
1         1/2/01 4
1         3/2/01 6
1         10/2/01 7
2         1/1/01  2
2         4/3/01  3"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```